# How to use "where" command and echo the result to .txt file and set that same .txt file as a variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm somewhat familiar with batch files but only use it as a personal hobby (e.g. for fun).

I'm mostly stumped on how I go about "echoing" the results to the text file.

Example:

```
where /r C:\ "search for this file.txt"
```

> C:\Users\Me\Desktop\search for this file.txt

** echo ('results') > results.txt **

```
set /p var= < results.txt
```

** How do I go about doing this? **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you're just missing an output there...

```
where /r C:\ "search for this file.txt" > results.txt
set /p var= < results.txt
```

if you want to display it to the console, you could either `echo %var%` after setting the var, or `type results.txt` after running the `where`.

Comment: No problem - happens to the best of us ;) you may've gotten hung up on the idea of dealing with what's echoed?  either way, if this was helpful consider marking it as the accepted answer for future readers of this post.

Comment: Accepted :) Thanks again.